# program does not work properly when moved to Servlet

Tags: java, file, servlets

I have made a program that works perfectly well in java class.. but when I moved my code to a servlet it does not work as expected
the program creates some files writes to them then later reads from them.. the problem is when I move the code to servlet the program would not create files in the first place, so when later reading them it will give FileNotFound exception

this is how I create write to and read from files.

first, create file and write to it
...

```
Writer output = null;
            File file = new File(i + ".txt");
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            output.write(text);
            output.close();
```

... then later read from file

```
 File file = new File(i+".txt");
            Scanner br = new Scanner(file);
           // BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(TDM.class.getResource(i + ".txt").getPath())));
            while (br.hasNextLine()) {
                line = br.nextLine();
```

...

Notes:
*the above code is NOT in servlet.. servlet only CALL the method that contains this code.
*apparently, the PROBLEM is with creating the file.. for some reason the file is not created when the method is called from servlet. how ever it works perfectly when called from another java class.

thanks in advance

Comment: We'll need more details, of course, about what exception gets thrown during "not create files in the first place", but I'm guessing you are looking at come permissions problem.  Like the servlet container is not running as a user that has write permissions where ever you are putting this.

Comment: Which servlet container? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975416/accessing-local-filesystem-on-the-server-from-a-servlet

Comment: The value of `i` is crucial here. Files you have access to when run on the desktop may not be accessible from the web server. There are clear rules about the working directory of a `Servlet`. More info is needed if you want people on SO to help you.

Comment: @BobKuhar this is the exception "SEVERE: java.io.FileNotFoundException: 1.txt (No such file or directory)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
 at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:636)
 at TDM.initiate(TDM.java:29)"

Comment: @BobKuhar .. I am currently running the program in Netbeans on my laptop.. what more details you need?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch actually the whole dealing with files does not happens in the servlet.. it happens in a method in a java class and servlet only calls that method .. does "which servlet container" still makes a difference

Comment: @BrunoLowagie i is a number from 1 to 10 .. I named my files 1.txt to 10.txt .. and I run my program on netbeans on my laptop and will not upload it to a server.. by "rules" do you mean rules of (where) the .txt files should be created and saved?

Comment: You need to specify a path to your files.

Comment: What Elliott says: the working directory of a standalone application is different from the working directory of a `Servlet`. You also need to check if your application server has the right permissions to write to/read that directory.

Comment: Something doesn't add up here.  In my experience, if the writes succeed, the reads will too barring any permissions exceptions.  Methinks somewhere along the line your write is swallowing an exception.

Comment: @BobKuhar thanks that worked! but what if I want to pass the file path as a parameter from servlet to a method in java class? I passed it as "file:/ ...path" and it is not working

Comment: now it works fine but I get an exception with jsoup! "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup" I don't want to edit something critical that would ruin the whole project :$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this comment from  "Elliott Frisch" solved my problem

> "You need to specify a path to your files."

simply I had to provide the "absolute" path instead of relative path
so, the code should be like this

```
 Writer output = null;
            File file = new File("/file/path/"i + ".txt");
            output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
            output.write(text);
            output.close();
```

and

```
 File file = new File("/file/path/"i+".txt");
            Scanner br = new Scanner(file);
           // BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(TDM.class.getResource(i + ".txt").getPath())));
            while (br.hasNextLine()) {
                line = br.nextLine();
```

then when I had this exception `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jsoup/Jsoup` I just had to downlad the jsoup library from the internet and add it to my project under (library folder).

thank you very much for you all :)

Answer (score 2):

Use a path: [File.createTempFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) for temporary files, or convert a web path ("/.../...") relative to your web contents into a file system File:

```
File file =
    request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INF/files/" + i + ".txt");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
...
```

Better yet give URLs to a file, that will be delivered by a Servlet streaming the file to

```
response.setContentType("text/plain");
response.getOutputStream();
...
```

If you write resource "files," that may reside in a .war of .jar; then do not use File.
Read them using an InputStream:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResource("/...").getResourceAsStream();
```

And copy them to the response.getOutputStream().

Also do not use the utility "short-hand" class FileWriter as it uses the platform encoding, which on Windows is some ANSI encoding and on Linux servers in general is UTF-8.

```
new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter
   (new FileOutputStream(file), "UTF-8"));
```